# Index generated column in mysql frequently updated

Tags: sql, mysql, database, indexing

I'm working on a project involving posts, each having number of likes and dislikes.

In my database, the 'posts' table contains columns for likes, dislikes, category, and user_id.

Additionally, there's a 'score' column that is generated column from number of likes minus dislikes for each post.

My current task is to retrieve the top posts within a given category, sorting them by score. Furthermore, I need to identify the top 20 users within each category based on their aggregated scores from their posts.

My question is, I want to make an index for the score column to speed up ordering and query, but that column value changes every seconds because many users will like and dislike posts and the score column value will change so frequently also index and everyone suggest to not create an index on frequently changed column.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a [mre]

Comment: How is this related to php?

Comment: @Adi this is project for php , so why not to consult with people who know php how to resolve maybe better way with php not just mysql.

Comment: Your question is not actually a question.

Comment: Show us the query; _then_ we can help with the `INDEX`.

Answer (score 2):

I think even with an index on the `score` calculated column, you'll still have to bear the cost of a table-scan when you want to find the top 20 users per category by aggregated score.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  post_id serial primary key,
  likes int,
  dislikes int,
  category int,
  user_id int,
  content text,
  score int as (likes - dislikes),
  key (score)
);

EXPLAIN
with cte1 as (
  select category, user_id, sum(score) as total_score
  from posts
  group by category, user_id
), cte2 as (
  select category, user_id, total_score,
    row_number() over (partition by category order by total_score desc) as rownum
  from cte1
)
select * from cte2 where rownum <= 20;
```

If I use EXPLAIN to analyze this query, I see it doesn't use the index regardless. It does a table-scan (`type: ALL`).

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 |    50.00 | Using where     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3> | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | Using filesort  |
|  3 | DERIVED     | posts      | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using temporary |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Dear Bill thank you for you answer, you answer will help me to better understand possible index costs